# fire the click event for each check box in GridViewCheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, telerik

I am using RadGridView.
I have bounded a table to the grid and I have created an `GridViewCheckBoxColumn` and bound a bool column to it.
I need to fire a method when one of the check boxes is fired in this column but none of the related events are fired by checking the check box.(note that there is not any click event in the `GridViewCheckBoxColumn` column and other events like `MouseLeftButtonDown`, `PropertyChanged`, `TextInput` are not fired by checking/unchecking the check box.
the column is created by the below code:

```
Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn newColumn;
if (columnInfo.typeOfColumn != null && columnInfo.typeOfColumn == typeof(bool))
{
    newColumn = new GridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    ((GridViewCheckBoxColumn)newColumn).DataMemberBinding =new Binding(columnInfo.id);
    ((GridViewCheckBoxColumn)newColumn).EditTriggers= GridViewEditTriggers.CellClick;
    ((GridViewCheckBoxColumn)newColumn).TextAlignment= TextAlignment.Center;
    ((GridViewCheckBoxColumn) newColumn).AutoSelectOnEdit = true;
}
```

Comment: what is the code related to _columnInfo.id_ property? Does that class implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: @Ramin - this is the class that hold the properties of the columns. this class is of own and does not have any effect. i creates the columns based on the list of this class and i will find the columnType and others setting of the column based on this class for each column.

Comment: Is not it easy to monitor property instead of UI? There is no real checkboxes in cells, everything is drawn

Comment: @Spawn - you are right but unfortunately the data source is a datatable that tracing its changes to find if the checkbox is clicked is time/memory consuming. do you have any idea for that?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used RadGridView before but did you check the events on the grid view itself not just the column? if not check this path :
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/events/overview especially selection events section.

Comment: i have used CellValidating, CellValidated and CurrentCellChanged events on the radGridView. they works on the specific conditions. for example, i need to immediatly capture the checkbox change but none of the above events can do that.

Comment: mmmm can you check the edit events :http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/events/edit

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking about CellEditElement, it's really CheckBox there, so we can make something like this:

code behind

```
private void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}

private void OnUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

In XAML:

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGeneratingColumn="RadGridView_AutoGeneratingColumn">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <EventSetter Event="Checked" Handler="OnChecked"/>
            <EventSetter Event="Unchecked" Handler="OnUnchecked"/>
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

We only must remember, that actual value will be in datatable after exit from cell.